# ReactJS error when using animations

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I have a working ReactJS app and I am attempting to use animations (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

I am trying to apply the transition animation to table rows as they are added. The existing working render looks like this:

```
return React.DOM.tbody({ valign: 'top' }, rows);
```

I have tried switching to this:

```
return React.DOM.tbody({ valign: 'top' }, React.createElement(ReactCSSTransitionGroup, {transitionName: "example"}, rows));
```

But I am now getting a warning and an error in the console:

> React attempted to use reuse markup in a container but the checksum
>   was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering
>   and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was
>   expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you
>   have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure
>   out why the markup being generated is different on the client or
>   server.
>
> Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Root element ID differed from
>   reactRootID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed something obvious. The docs say:

> By default ReactTransitionGroup renders as a *span*

So it was creating invalid markup within the table. I have set the component= property to "tr" which now works.